# dotnet run not working with worker service access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, service-worker, .net-7.0

I was working over a worker service I create and it works fine but today while editing the code, dotnet run command just started to fail with the next error message.

I didn't touch anything what could cause this. Anyone knows something?.

> Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): An error occurred trying to start process
> 'C:\Users\Some folder...\Some Folder...\Some Folder...\WorkerService.exe' with working directory 'C:\Users\SomeFolder\Desktop\WorkerServiceFolder'. Access denied.

I already try reset my PC, the vs code, create a new worker service to try to reply and it says the same thing with only the default code so I thing it is something else but I don't understand what is happening.

I also try to reset settings.json, powershell as administrator, re-install runtime, so whats wrong.

Comment: Could you tell us the latest progress of the issue ?

Comment: It was a problem of security and user authorization/permission settings at my job, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the project to another disk, like D: drive for testing. It can verify the issue related to permisiion or not.

Check if there is anti-virus software running, you can temporarily stop it.

Finally, check the logs in Eventviewer to see if there are any useful error messages left when the problem occurs.